# How to get order_id in Razor Pay Payment Gateway?

Tags: django, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am looking for the **order_id** from the razorpay to save in the database, how do i get that in views.py to save in database.

> Payment is successfully done by the razerpay but I want to retrieve
>   that order_id.

I am getting the below error

> module 'razorpay.client' has no attribute 'order'

### urls.py

```
app_name = "checkout"

urlpatterns = [
    path('payment/', payment, name="payment"),
    path('checkout-form', checkout, name='checkout-form'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def checkout(request):
    user = request.user
    carts = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
    orders = Order.objects.filter(user=user, ordered=False)
    order = orders[0]
    amount = int(order.get_totals() * 100)
    context = {
        "carts": carts,
        'order': order,
        'amount': amount,
    }
    return render(request, 'checkout-form.html', context)


def payment(request):
    order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    amount = int(order.get_totals() * 100)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(" request is post ")
        order_amount = amount,
        order_currency = "INR",
        order_receipt = 'order_rcptid_11'
        course = client.order.create(amount=order_amount,
                                     currency=order_currency,
                                     receipt=order_receipt,
                                     payment_capture='0')
        # Create the Payment    
        payment = Payment()
        payment.razorpay_order_ID = course['id'][0]
        payment.user = request.user
        payment.amount = int(order.get_totals())
        payment.save()
        print("this is the post payment method")
    else:
        # order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
        # context = {
        #     'order': order
        # }
        print(" request is get")
        return render(request, 'checkout-form.html')
    return redirect('checkout:payment/')
```

#### checkout.html

```
<form action="{% url 'checkout:payment' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
     data-key="######################"
     data-amount="{{ amount }}"
     data-currency="INR"
     data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
     data-name="Acme Corp"
     data-description="A Wild Sheep Chase is the third novel by Japanese author Haruki Murakami"
     data-image="https://example.com/your_logo.jpg"
     data-prefill.name="Gaurav Kumar"
     data-prefill.email="gaurav.kumar@example.com"
     data-prefill.contact="9999999999"
     data-theme.color="#F37254" > </script>
     <input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Panwar you have to pass `order id` to your html page inside your script

```
def payment(request):
    order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    amount = int(order.get_totals() * 100)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(" request is post ")
        order_amount = amount,
        order_currency = "INR",
        order_receipt = 'order_rcptid_11'
        course = client.order.create(dict(amount=order_amount,
                                     currency=order_currency,
                                     receipt=order_receipt,
                                     payment_capture='0'))
        context = {}
        context['order_id'] = course['id']
        return render(request, 'checkout-form.html',context)
    else:
        # order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
        # context = {
        #     'order': order
        # }
        print(" request is get")
        return render(request, 'checkout-form.html')
    return redirect('checkout:payment/')
```

and inside your template you have to give `order_id` to your `razorpay` api

```
<form action="{% url 'checkout:payment_status' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
     data-key="######################"
     data-amount="{{ amount }}"
     data-currency="INR"
     data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
     data-name="Acme Corp"
     data-order_id = {{ order_id }}
     data-description="A Wild Sheep Chase is the third novel by Japanese author Haruki Murakami"
     data-image="https://example.com/your_logo.jpg"
     data-prefill.name="Gaurav Kumar"
     data-prefill.email="gaurav.kumar@example.com"
     data-prefill.contact="9999999999"
     data-theme.color="#F37254" > </script>
     <input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
</form>
```

and than verify signature inside `payment_status`

```
def payment_status(request):

    response = request.POST

    params_dict = {
        'razorpay_payment_id' : response['razorpay_payment_id'], # this you have to get from ajax call
        'razorpay_order_id' : response['razorpay_order_id'],
        'razorpay_signature' : response['razorpay_signature']
    }


    # VERIFYING SIGNATURE
    try:
        status = client.utility.verify_payment_signature(params_dict)
        payment = Payment()
        payment.razorpay_order_ID = course['id'][0]
        payment.user = request.user
        payment.amount = int(order.get_totals())
        payment.save() # you canto save all the important details return by razorpay eg. `razorpay_payment_id`, `razorpay_signature` 
        return render(request, 'order_summary.html', {'status': 'Payment Successful'})
    except:
        return render(request, 'order_summary.html', {'status': 'Payment Faliure!!!'})
```

for more information refer this post [Integrating Razorpay with django](https://medium.com/@dk521/integrating-razorpay-with-django-91302dcd9adb)